# React Fullstack: not able to fetch item details from Rest API

Tags: reactjs, django, api, rest

Im working on a fullstack django and react application, which for now just fetches the data from the django api, also im able to fetch the detail page of the first item present on the react list page but cannot do the same for the second item. It shows following error when i try to fetch the second item from django (strange but it works fine with the first item of id = 1 and not for id = 2 or 3).

[image]

Also, I pushed my whole code on bitbucket. You can debug both frontend and backend here https://bitbucket.org/Yash-Marmat/react-django-blog/src/master/

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your urls looks strange. Try to change urls:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', ArticleListView.as_view()),
    path('detail/<int:pk>/', ArticleDetailView.as_view()),
]
```

and access with a changed URL in the frontend. I can recommend a [good tutorial for Django+React CRUD](https://saasitive.com/tutorial/crud-django-rest-framework-react/).

Comment: thanks, but still the same error, also i too think that i need to use a different approach for this. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable cors or cross origin resource sharing in your django api

You can do this by installing this package called django-cors-headers

[Django cors headers github page](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers)

```bash
    pip install django-cors-headers
```

and then add it to your installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
)
```

You will also need to add a middleware class to listen in on responses:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',  
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',  
    ...
)

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True # If this is used then `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` will not have any effect
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost:3030',
] # If this is used, then not need to use `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True`
CORS_ORIGIN_REGEX_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost:3030',
]
```

more details: https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/#configuration

reading the official documentation can resolve almost all problem

Comment: thanks but it still showing the same error :(

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `proxy` key in inside frontend `package.json` file as shown bellow

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
```

and restart the react application.

Comment: thanks but it still showing the same error :(

Comment: try giving different port for API server.

Comment: i think the approach i used is not right or old (was following an old youtube tutorial, 3 years old) so now im using a complete different approach for my project. So, no longer working on it. But thanks again for the suggestions buddy. Also i cant accept the answer but i do upvote you ️